# Get all work items from a project azure devops REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Azure devops API to create a notification bot with AWS Lambda node.js. At this moment i need to check if each task work item is attached to a parent user story.

The first step will be to get all the task work items on "given" project, for this step i was reading azure devops api documentation and found this: [Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#get-list-of-work-items)

The API is asking for the id of the workitem that i want to get, but what if i need all the workitems from "given" project?

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&api-version=5.1
```

Or is there any other way to get all the workitem ids from a given project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Work Items - Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API that doesn't require ids but the maximum work items in the results are 200.

But, if you need to check Tasks, why you need get **all** the work items in the project? you can get only the Tasks, with [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body) API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1
```

In the body make the query:

```
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'"
}
```

Comment: How do you make this POST request? I am using Python and have a PAT...cannot figure this out. where will the PAT go?

Comment: Don't know about Python, but in Node, we pass PAT as an Authorization header

Comment: The Work Items - Get Work Items Batch api now requires the ids parameter in the request body.

Answer (score 2):

Furthering Shayki's response regarding using a WIQL query, I'd suggest that you can have two birds with one stone here by doing a work item links query that looks for Tasks without a parent User Story:

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1`

request payload:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse') AND ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story') MODE (DoesNotContain)"
}
```

This way, you won't have to loop through each work item to then check if it has a parent.

Note: the WIQL query limits the results returned to 20K and returns an error if the query results in more work items than that. Further reason to use a query like the above, if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a client for C#:

```
        public IEnumerable<int> GetIdList()
        {
            var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://yourazuredevopsurl/"), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));
            var workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            var wiql = new Wiql
            {
                Query =  $@"Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case'"
            };
            
            var worItemsIds = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql, "Project name").Result;

            return worItemsIds.WorkItems.Select(reference => reference.Id);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works well - remember to declare the url, body and PAT variables first (you can use somthing like getpass for PAT):

```
r = requests.post(url, json=body,
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    auth = ('', PAT))
print(r.content)
```