# Interacting with AzureDevops using python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to achieve following things while interacting with AzureDevops using python:

1. To get the *stories* under **Boards** section
2. To get the *branches* under **Repos** section

I am able to establish connection to AzureDevops URL using **requests** API, but not sure how to read the data using it.
Is there any way by which I can do the same or if there is some other API using which I can do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Sharma, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej,

We could use write a WIQL query to list all User Story, you could refer this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-samples/blob/master/src/samples/work_item_tracking.py) for more details.

```
from vsts.vss_connection import VssConnection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import json
from vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.models.wiql import Wiql

def emit(msg, *args):
print(msg % args)

def print_work_item(work_item):
    emit(
        "{0} {1}: {2}".format(
            work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
            work_item.id,
            work_item.fields["System.Title"],
        )
    )

personal_access_token = 'YourPATToken'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/YourorgName'
# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = VssConnection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
wiql = Wiql(
        query="""select [System.Id] From WorkItems """
    )

wit_client = connection.get_client('vsts.work_item_tracking.v4_1.work_item_tracking_client.WorkItemTrackingClient')
wiql_results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(wiql).work_items
if wiql_results:
        # WIQL query gives a WorkItemReference with ID only
        # => we get the corresponding WorkItem from id
        work_items = (
            wit_client.get_work_item(int(res.id)) for res in wiql_results
        )
        for work_item in work_items:
            print_work_item(work_item)
```

2. List all branches, we could use [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and add variable `filter` to list all branches, If we do not add it, it will also list pull request.

Sample:
List all repo and get repo ID.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=4.1
```

List repo branches via repo ID

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo ID}/refs?filter=heads&api-version=4.1
```

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

Power shell script

```
#List all branches name    
$connectionToken="PAT"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $BranchDetailURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo ID}/refs?filter=heads&?api-version=6.0" 
    $BranchInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BranchDetailURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 
    Write-Host $BranchInfo.value.name
    
#List all User Story ID

    $WorkItemWiqlQuery = "https://dev.azure.com/v-viliu/test_Agile/test/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1"
    $query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'"
    $body = @{query=$query} | ConvertTo-Json
    $WorkItemDetailInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WorkItemWiqlQuery -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} -Body $body
    
    Write-Host $WorkItemDetailInfo.workItems.id
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Sharma, I have updated the answer and shared the power shell script here, you could check it and then kindly share the result here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get stories please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021711/2347999) but keep in mind to set proper filter  `[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'"`.

To get branches you need to use [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) endpoint

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=6.0
```

Sample response

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/feature/calcApp",
      "objectId": "ffe9cba521f00d7f60e322845072238635edb451",
      "creator": {
        "displayName": "Normal Paulk",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/ac5aaba6-a66a-4e1d-b508-b060ec624fa9",
        "_links": {
          "avatar": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.YmFjMGYyZDctNDA3ZC03OGRhLTlhMjUtNmJhZjUwMWFjY2U5"
          }
        },
        "id": "ac5aaba6-a66a-4e1d-b508-b060ec624fa9",
        "uniqueName": "dev@mailserver.com",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=ac5aaba6-a66a-4e1d-b508-b060ec624fa9",
        "descriptor": "aad.YmFjMGYyZDctNDA3ZC03OGRhLTlhMjUtNmJhZjUwMWFjY2U5"
      },
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/7484f783-66a3-4f27-b7cd-6b08b0b077ed/_apis/git/repositories/d3d1760b-311c-4175-a726-20dfc6a7f885/refs?filter=heads%2Ffeature%2FcalcApp"
    },
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/feature/replacer",
      "objectId": "917131a709996c5cfe188c3b57e9a6ad90e8b85c",
      "creator": {
        "displayName": "Normal Paulk",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/ac5aaba6-a66a-4e1d-b508-b060ec624fa9",
        "_links": {
          "avatar": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.YmFjMGYyZDctNDA3ZC03OGRhLTlhMjUtNmJhZjUwMWFjY2U5"
          }
        },
        "id": "ac5aaba6-a66a-4e1d-b508-b060ec624fa9",
        "uniqueName": "dev@mailserver.com",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=ac5aaba6-a66a-4e1d-b508-b060ec624fa9",
        "descriptor": "aad.YmFjMGYyZDctNDA3ZC03OGRhLTlhMjUtNmJhZjUwMWFjY2U5"
      },
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/7484f783-66a3-4f27-b7cd-6b08b0b077ed/_apis/git/repositories/d3d1760b-311c-4175-a726-20dfc6a7f885/refs?filter=heads%2Ffeature%2Freplacer"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!!
I am pretty new to this but somehow I managed to get the connection established with ADO as following:
response = requests.get("https://dev.azure.com/{company_name}/_git/{project_name}/", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, p))

Can I modify this somehow to get this piece of code interacting with ADO?

Comment: Hi @YogeshSharma, do you mind getting the result via power shell? If yes, I can share the script here and you could try it, then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Madej, please share that; will try with Powershell also.